# ItoProcess and/or RandomFunction numerical failure for coupled SDEs

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, random, stochastic-calculus

I'm trying to simulate a physical system including noise using the `ItoProcess` command, the system is governed by two coupled differential equations. The potential is

```
pot = 1/2k(x[t]-v t)^2+(c1+c2 q[t]^2)(1-Cos[2Pi(x[t]-c4 q[t])/a])+ c3 q[t]^4;
```

The resulting coupled system is

```
s = 
    NDSolve[{-mx x''[t] - D[pot, x[t]] - mx nx (x'[t]) == 0, -mq q''[t] - 
    D[pot, q[t]] - mq nq (q'[t]) == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0, q[0] == 0, 
    q'[0] == 0}, {x[t], q[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}];
```

which is readily solved by `NDSolve`. However, adding noise to the system, it is transformed into a system of coupled stochastic differential equations, and we need(?) to use an Ito Process in order to simulate it in Mathematica.

The corresponding Ito Process is

```
s = 
   ItoProcess[{
      \[DifferentialD]x[t] == \[DifferentialD]t xx[t], 
      \[DifferentialD]q[t] == \[DifferentialD]t qq[t], 
      \[DifferentialD]xx[t] == \[DifferentialD]t/(-mx) (D[pot, x[t]] 
      + mx nx (xx[t])) + \[DifferentialD]xnoise, 
      \[DifferentialD]qq[t] == \[DifferentialD]t/(-mq) (D[pot, q[t]]
      + mq nq (qq[t])) + \[DifferentialD]qnoise}, 
      {x[t], xx[t], q[t], qq[t]}, {{x, xx, q, qq}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, 
      {t, 0}, {xnoise \[Distributed] WienerProcess[0, 1*^-7],
      qnoise \[Distributed] WienerProcess[0, 1*^-8]}]

randsamp = RandomFunction[s, {0, 5*^-9, 1*^-11}]
```

However, when I run the above command I get the errors

`General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation.`

and

```
Experimental`NumericalFunction::nlnum: The function value {4.203331994982121*10^537,Overflow[],-4.353127001287732*10^1169869785968746,Overflow[]} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {4} at {t,x,xx,q,qq,RandomProcesses`SimulationDump`dt$151646,RandomProcesses`SimulationDump`dw$151646$151647,RandomProcesses`SimulationDump`dw$151646$151648} = {6.8*10^-10,2.143699317440867*10^539,4.203331994982092*10^548,-5.344814277012275*10^694021436388771,-4.353127001287702*10^1169869785968757,1.*10^-11,-0.329753,-0.163157}.
```

For reference, the parameter values used are

```
k = 1.0*^0; 
v = 1*^0; 
c1 = 1.3*^-20; 
c2 = 0.2*^0;
c3 = 8*^18; 
c4 = 1*^0;
a = 2.5*^-10;
mx = 1*^-23;
mq = 5*^-22;
nx = 3*^12;
nq = 3*^12;
h = 1*^-15;
tmax = 5000000 h;
```

and the x[t] solution should look like

[image]

I fail to see why such humongous numbers should appear. Especially, since everything seems fine when using `NDSolve`. I've tried removing the noise part by multiplying the `xnoise` and `qnoise` by 0, that doesn't work. My best guess is that the problem has to do with the exponents of the parameters being very far apart. Still, they work fine for `NDSolve`, and increasing `WorkingPrecision` does not solve the issue.

Comment: Just a marginal comment: why do you need the copies `xx[t], qq[t]` ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I understand the question, or rather what you mean by "copies"? xx[t] and qq[t] is x'[t] and q'[t] in Ito notation, which are physically interesting variables, is that an answer to your question?

Comment: Yes, my misunderstanding, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your ODE solution, it looks like there are brief bursts when `x` changes rapidly.  This suggests a simple solution: make your step size much smaller.

```
s = ItoProcess[{
  \[DifferentialD]x[t] == \[DifferentialD]t xx[t],
  \[DifferentialD]q[t] == \[DifferentialD]t qq[t],
  \[DifferentialD]xx[t] == \[DifferentialD]t (-D[pot, x[t]]/mx - nx xx[t]) + \[DifferentialD]xnoise[t],
  \[DifferentialD]qq[t] == \[DifferentialD]t (-D[pot, q[t]]/mq - nq qq[t]) + \[DifferentialD]qnoise[t]},
  {x[t], xx[t], q[t], qq[t]}, {{x, xx, q, qq}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, t,
  {xnoise \[Distributed] WienerProcess[0, 10^6],
  qnoise \[Distributed] WienerProcess[0, 10^6]}];

randsamp = RandomFunction[s, {0, 5*^-9, 1*^-13}];

ListPlot[randsamp["PathComponent", 1]] (* x[t] vs t *)
ListPlot[randsamp["PathComponent", 2], PlotRange -> All] (* xx[t] vs t *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that I had to really crank up the noise amplitude to even see any effect of noise.

Comment: Well, that's a bit anti-climatically simple, and here I thought I had come up with some involved stuff, haha! The noise being so significantly increased _is_ a bit weird to me at this moment, but I'll look into that...

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area, but I suspect the need for large noise is because your time of integration is so short.